# Copying datarow from one datatable to another fails with DataTable.Importrow method?

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to copy some rows from one datatable to another, here's the code I'm using:-

```
DataTable dt_query;
public void show_query(int page)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda_query = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from query where resolved='NO'", conn);
    conn.Close();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda_query.Fill(dt);
    dt_query.Clear();
    for (int i = (page - 1) * 5; i < page * 5 && i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt_query.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
    }
    GridView2.DataSource = dt_query;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

But the gridview ends up showing 5 blank rows with only the auto generated select button. What is wrong here?

The HTML of he gridview is as follow:-

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" 
    runat="server" Width="820px" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="4" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the asp grid?

Answer (score 0):

try closing the connection after the fill method. Also, try to do this without the dt_query table.

```
public void show_query(int page)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sda_query = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from query where resolved='NO'", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda_query.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: But the scenerio is that datatable dt contains say 7 rows and I want the gridview to show only first 5 rows

Comment: ok, we'll get there, just tell me if this code works, and we'll go from there! :)

Comment: yeah this one works. Anyway, I got what I wanted by cloning dt_query first as dt, then importing the rows... thanks anyways

Comment: i think GridView2.DataSource = dt_query; would have also worked